# Flat json to nested json python

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas, dictionary

I want to convert input json to nested json defined, I am not able to think of any json library which help me achieve this

Input json

```
[{'Name': 'John', 'state': 'Boston', 'currency': 'USD', 'marks': 100},
{'Name': 'Rohan', 'state': 'Paris', 'currency': 'EUR', 'marks': 20},
{'Name': 'Rohan', 'state': 'Lyon', 'currency': 'EUR', 'marks': 11.4},
{'Name': 'Messi', 'state': 'Madrid', 'currency': 'EUR', 'marks': 9.9},
{'Name': 'Lampard', 'state': 'London', 'currency': 'GBP', 'marks': 12.2},
{'Name': 'Lampard', 'state': 'London', 'currency': 'FBP', 'marks': 10.9}]
```

output json

```
{
  "USD": {
    "John": {
      "Boston": [
        {
          "Marks": 100
        }
      ]
    },
```

Current scenario based on value Currency,Name,state,marks

The nested json can be put upto n level if required such as Name and state and marks or it can be Name , curreny , state and marks or Name,curreny and marks

Comment: What's the relationship between `n` and the keys?

Comment: We need to know: What are the inputs? Edit your question with expected inputs and expected outputs. In your final sentence, you say "up to n level", but then list 2 different outcomes with 3 levels, and 2 with 4 levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want currency > name > state > list of marks.

One solution would be to create the structure using `defaultdict`s, and then just add to it.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import wraps

data = [...]

def ddmaker(type_):
    @wraps(dict)
    def caller():
        return defaultdict(type_)
    return caller

# create the structure of the output
output = defaultdict(ddmaker(ddmaker(list)))

# add to it
for item in data:
    currency = item["currency"]
    name = item["Name"]
    state = item["state"]
    mark = item["marks"]

    output[currency][name][state].append({'Marks': mark})
```

Comment: Not necessarily the output can have  currency > name > state > list of marks it can also be like this  name > currency > state > list of marks or this state > currency > name > list of marks.

Comment: @Coderun what indicates what form it's in? In any case, surely you can now work out what to do?

Comment: yes, i can change that in the code, can you guide how to print the output @blueteeth

Comment: it doesnt give the exact output @blueteeth

Comment: `output` is a dict. If you want JSON you can use the [json module in the stdlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: can we make it dynamic, if I want to see the nested till currency  Name and marks ? @blueteeth

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Please edit you question with more details of what needs to be dynamic, what the input is, and what the output should be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233320/discussion-between-code-run-and-blueteeth).